# ASP.NET MVC placing userID in hidden field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor

I am trying to apply the membership userID to a hidden field so that I can associate table data to a spceific user.

(users completes a form that is stored in a table, userID used to associate to login profile)

I just don't know how to do this and is an important part of my current project and future projects.

Any guidance, advice, links to solutions would be of great help as I am completely at a loss with this.

I tried passing the data from the model class for the view but I get an error saying "The name 'User' does not exist in the current context"

this is an extract of my model class

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Security;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;


namespace mySite_Site.Models
{

    [Table("accountInfo")] // Table name
    public class accountInfo
    {
        [Key]
        public int AccountID { get; set; }
        public int UserIdent { get; set; } //this is the field that would store the userID for association
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Locality { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastLoggedIn { get; set; }

        public string UserIdentity = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Brandon O'Dell's answer, using "Membership" in that block of code didn't work for me (unhandled errors).  Nevertheless, I think his approach to this solution is great because it means you can call the current user's Id from practically anywwhere. So, I went on ahead and played a little bit with the code, and voilá!.

In case using "Membership" doesn't work for you as well, try this one:

```
using <your project's name>.Models

public class GeneralHelpers
{
    public static string GetUserId()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        return user.Id;
    }
}
```

This one gets the whole user, so, you can create even more methods inside this "GeneralHelper" class (or whatever name you wish to give it) to get the current user's info and use it in your application.

Thanks, Brandon!

Answer (score 2):

You just need something like this, assuming your ViewModel has the user profile on it.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.UserProfile.UserId)
```

Comment: I tried this in my model - public string UserIdentity = User.Identity.GetUserId(); but was getting the following error "the name User does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @user2029541 sounds like your problem isn't about a hidden field at all.

Comment: Could you elaborate please Mike

Comment: @user2029541 Like Mike said, sounds like a hidden field isn't your issue. Why not post a little code sample showing what isn't working and we can take a look

Comment: @user2029541 well, you can't set the value of a hidden field if you can't even get the value without throwing an error. If you can set the UserId in your model, then the code above will work. If you can't set the UserId at all, then that is your problem. More code (model) will help.

Comment: @user2029541 - Based on your comments, I have added the reason your model is not working correctly when you are initializing it.  Please take a look and see if that helps get the user id.

Answer (score 2):

Since your model is not in the controller, you need to explicitly tell the code *Where* the user object is, which is contained in the HttpContext.  So, update this line here:

```
public string UserIdentity = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

to the following

```
public string UserIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

The controller and view base classes have a reference to the current HttpContext, which is why you can shortcut in those items and simply use `User.Identity`.  Anywhere else in your project, you will need the fully qualified `HttpContext.Current.User`.

**Edit**

In further looking at your code, it looks like you are trying to save the user Id as a column in your database.  In that instance, I think (based on your code sample) that you should remove that last part - `public string UserIdentity = User.Identity.GetUserId();`. When you save a new account info object, that is where you would save the user id.

```
var info = new accountInfo();
accountInfo.UserIdent = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
db.accountInfos.Add(info);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Tommy thanks, it makes more sense now, I wasn't thinking in that way, a lot more logical to directly save the info rather than passing it to the form first.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a static helper class?

```
    public static class UserUtils
    {
        public static object GetUserId()
        {
            return Membership
                .GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
                .ProviderUserKey;           
        }
    }
```